# What kind melanin do fair or light skinned black or mixed people have, eumelanin of pheomelanin?

Tags: melanin

I am doing a study on melanin and conductivity but I cannot find the answer to this question anywhere. Do light complected black or biracial people have eumelanin or pheomelanin? or both?

Comment: Race is not a biological construct, which is why asking this question from a racial perspective is not productive. All major variants associated with pigmentation (including the production of eumelanin and pheomelanin) had evolved a very long time ago and were selected upon as humans migrated from Africa. People of African descent, being the most genetically diverse group of humans on the planet, vary greatly in pigmentation, because they represent that initial pool of variants https://science.sciencemag.org/content/358/6365/eaan8433

Answer (score 1):

Pheomelanin is associated with paler skin, while eumelanin predomominates in people with darker skin — this is influenced by alleles of the MC1R gene [Swope and Abdel-Malek, 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6163888/), [NIH article on MC1R](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/MC1R).